# Adding event handlers dynamically based on className

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React function component, where I get another component in props. Something like this:

```
function ChildComponent({cmp}) {
    // Here onClick handlers should be added [for example:
    // () => console.log("clicked")] to all
    // elements in cmp of class .clickable

    return ...
}

function ParentComponent() {
    return (
        <ChildComponent cmp={<div><button>Non-clickable</button><button className="clickable">Clickable</button></div>} />
    )
}
```

So how to add event handlers dynamically to elements with class *clickable* in the *cmp* props variable in the *ChildComponent*?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Where do you want your onClick handler in, your ParentComponent or your ChildComponent?

Comment: In the ChildComponent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses [Children](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren) API that allows you to modify children's props based on its current props.
The ChildComponent will first loop through its current children, look for `clickable` `className` props and add `onClick` handler to its props.

The recursion loop allows nested children to work too.

```
function ChildComponent({ cmp }) {
  const handleOnClick = () => {
    alert("Clicked");
  };

  const childrenMap = (child) => {
    if (child.props) {
      const newProps = Object.assign({}, child.props);
      const { children, className } = newProps;
      if (className && className.split(' ').some(cn => cn === 'clickable')) {
        newProps.onClick = handleOnClick;
      }
      if (children) {
        newProps.children = Children.map(children, childrenMap);
      }
      return cloneElement(child, newProps);
    }
    return child;
  }

  return Children.map(cmp, childrenMap);
}

function ParentComponent() {
  return (
    <ChildComponent
      cmp={(
        <div>
          <button>Non-clickable</button>
          <div>
            <div>
              <button className="clickable">Clickable</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <button className="clickable">Clickable</button>
        </div>
      )}
    />
  );
}
```